# scaling database diagram in sql server

Tags: sql-server, diagram, scale, visio

I have created a database diagram in sql server which is consist of number of tables.I need to copy the diagram in to a word document but when i copy it to the word document its not well formatted and some parts are even missing.is there any software to scale the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Microsoft Visio**.

You should refer the below links.

[1. Visio](http://www.sethi.org/classes/cet415/lab_notes/lab_03.html)

[2. Visio](http://softwaretopic.informer.com/database-diagram-microsoft-office/)

Comment: Definitely take the route through Visio - it'll make it so much easier (and prettier)